# Import qgis_core in pydev enviroment

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing my first plugin for qgis. the operating system is Windows 10 Enterprise. I use Eclipse -PyDev as my programing  enviroment. And has qgis installed as a standalone program. When i try:

```
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceURI,QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry
```

PyDev then warns me: 
[image: UnresolvedImport]

So when I run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\PluginNaeme\Source\theCode.py", line 9, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceURI,QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps an issue with your environment? Try checking the steps as described here (although a fairly old post): [Setting Up PyQGis Development Environment with PyDev on Windows](https://geographicprimitive.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/setting-up-pyqgis-development-environment-with-pydev-on-windows/)

Comment: Also this post might help: [Adding QGIS-specific Python interpreter to Eclipse?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183723/adding-qgis-specific-python-interpreter-to-eclipse)

Comment: use dependency walker on all qgis .so to check what dll is not found

Comment: The  [Setting Up PyQGis Development Environment with PyDev on Windows](https://geographicprimitive.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/setting-up-pyqgis-development-environment-with-pydev-on-windows/) worked for me. I had already tried the sugestion in [Adding QGIS-specific Python interpreter to Eclipse?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183723/adding-qgis-specific-python-interpreter-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

It means that the enviroment is't setup properly. And PyDev can't find the specified libraries.

So I used the solution from here to fix it: [Setting Up PyQGis Development Environment with PyDev on Windows](https://geographicprimitive.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/setting-up-pyqgis-development-environment-with-pydev-on-windows/) that @Josep told me in the comments. Thank you btw.

Replacing:

```
C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Tethys\apps\Python25
C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Tethys\apps\Python25\Lib
C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Tethys\apps\Python25\sip
C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Tethys\apps\qgis\python
```

With:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\Python27
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\Python27\Lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\Python27\sip
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python
```

Since I have a later version then in the link.

Finally i checked that it was working properly with:

```
try:
    import PyQt4.QtGui
    import PyQt4.QtCore
    from qgis.gui import *
    from qgis.core import *
finally: 
    print 'The import works! :)'
```

Comment: Nice one! Glad you got it working :)